# Select n first rows of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

How can I select, say top 100 rows of a matrix in R?
All I found is using subset which requires condition parameter. All I need to make smaller matrix by using only first n number of rows with same number of columns

Comment: You may likely just use `head(my.matrix,100)`, or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Dumbest question. I got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `head` function:

```
head(mat, 100)
```

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to do it would be `a[1:100,]` (unless there are fewer than 100 rows, in which case head(a,100) works better)

Comment: `head(a, 100)` is preferred.  If there are not `100` rows in `a`, using the `[` call will return an error.  Using `head` will give you all of the rows in `a`.   (ie, you can use the former programmatically:  `n <- 125;  head(a, n)` )

Comment: Yes, the two proposed approaches handle the case when `nrow(mat) < 100` differently. But I wouldn't say one approach is "preferred". Errors can be useful too.

Comment: Also `head` keeps the structure whereas `[` transforms it.